# Issue witch async in angular (listing elements from Web Api)

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

Here is the code snippet:

```
this.languages = await this.languageService.getAllLanguages().toPromise()

    this.languages.forEach(async (value, index) => {
      console.log(value.name)
      this.originLanguageOption.setDropdownOption (
        value.name,
        index
      )

      this.originLanguageOptions.push(
        this.originLanguageOption     
      )
    })

    this.originLanguageDropdown.setDropdown(
      'Origin language',
      'Choose Language',
      this.originLanguageOptions
    )
```

Issue:
Console log works fine, it is just list all the elements from DB, but when I try to assign data to 'this.originLanguageOptions', then it overrides all previous elements on the list. The array looks like:
1st loop:

- English

2nd loop:

- German
- German

3rd loop:

- France
- France
- France

etc.

It should looks like this:
3rd loop

- English
- German
- France

Comment: Can you add the code for this component?

Comment: It's not needed, friend below answered how to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each iteration of the foreach you are using setDropdownOption() on the same instance. I understand that you should create an option in each iteration and then add it to the array.

Comment: Omg, my face after moving creating option to loop: O.O, my brain after realizing how dumb i am sometimes: xD. Anyway, thanks :D